# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.1.1]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I wanted to save & retrieve data from **Firebase**, but when I pasted the links this weird error occurred
which is:

In root-level (project-level) Gradle file (`build.gradle`)

1. **inside dependencies**
   Implementation `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`
2. **At bottom**
   Apply plugin: `'com.google.gms.goole-services'`

In module (app-level) Gradle file (usually `app/build.gradle`

1. **inside dependencies**
   classpath `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

[image]

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVBpD.png)

Comment: Images of text are not accessible, searchable, or readable on small screen sizes. Please [edit] the question and include the relevant text and format it appropriately.

Comment: Sorry..! but I didn't get to what you are referring to, the image or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:-

just go back to the Google's **firebase** website & check each link's version in website (which will be at the end of the links eg: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`) & that you pasted in the Project Gradle & App Gradle & make sure the version of both website's & gradles are same.
Then after making them same just click on the 'sync now' which will be at top-right corner of Android Studio, when the syncing will be finished, you will be good to go to Run your project.

In a simple sentence - you just had to update your firebase links.

I hope this was helpful for you..